# Datatable row expansion Treetable

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

This example consists of listing the roles and for each role, I would like to display the groups and users associated with it.

XHTML

```
        <p:column headerText="Designation">
            <h:outputText value="#{rl.designation}" />
        </p:column>


            <p:rowExpansion>
                <p:treeTable value="#{roleMB.root}" var="document">
                  <p:column headerText="Designation">
                   <h:outputText value="#{document}" />
                   </p:column>
                 </p:treeTable>
            </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

CONTROLLER

Method used to display the treetable of each role.

```
public void createRoot(){
        List<AffectationRoleGroupe> groupesRole=new ArrayList<AffectationRoleGroupe>();
        for(Role rl:roles){

        root=new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);

        groupesRole=rl.getAffectationsRG();
        for(AffectationRoleGroupe a:groupesRole){
            System.out.println(rl.getDesignation());
            System.out.println(a.getGroupe().getDesignation());
            TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode( a.getGroupe().getDesignation(), root);
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are missing an rowToggle event that trigger the generation of list groupe of each role :

```
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{managedBean.createRoot(role)}" update=":treeGroupe" />

<p:rowExpansion>
    <p:treeTable id="treeGroupe" value="#{roleMB.root}" var="groupe">
        <p:column headerText="Designation">
            <h:outputText value="#{groupe.designation}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:treeTable>
</p:rowExpansion>
```

Second in your method you should pass the role that you are hundling, and then you have to fill the nodes of tree with the group of the role  :

```
public void createRoot(Role role){
    ......
}
```

you can see how to hundle treeTable : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/basic.xhtml